# Atomic operation on defined type

Tags: go

If I define a new type of 'State' like this:

```
type State int32
```

Could the value of type 'State' be applied with atomic operations, like 'atomic.StoreInt32()'？

If not, why?

If can, could it be applied as below?

```
func SetAndGet(s State, n State) State {
    si := int32(s)
    ni := int32(n)
    return State(atomic.SwapInt32(&si, ni))
}
```

---

Update:

The code is modified as below, according to @icza's answer.

```
func SetAndGetState(s *State, n State) State {
    return State(atomic.SwapInt32((*int32)(s), int32(n)))
}
func SetAndGetInt(s *int32, n int32) State {
    return State(atomic.SwapInt32((*int32)(s), int32(n)))
}
var s1 State = 1
var i1 int32 = 1
SetAndGetState(&s1, 2)
SetAndGetInt(&i1, 2)
```

I've tried the codes of mine and @icza's. And they all succeed. The result of 'State' seem to be the same as int32. What I want to know is: 
In high concurrency situation, does the atomic operations have the same concurrency effect on defined type 'State' as on 'int32'?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It might be much faster to just implement these three lines of code and test them then asking on SO? "Yes" is to short for an answer.

Comment: Sorry. I've added more details of what I want to know. The result I've tested seems to be right. But I wanna know if the defined type 'State' can be used instead of 'int32' in high concurrency situation when meeting atomic operations.

Answer (score 3):

Atomic operations are usually performed on a variable.

When you call a function, the values passed are copied. There is no reason to perform atomic operation on your local variables (function parameters) used only by your function.

You may want to perform atomic operations e.g. on a global variable. And for `SetAndGet()` to be able to do that, you have to pass its address (passing its value just copies it).

And you can't create a local copy of the pointer passed (neither the pointed value), you have to pass the address you get directly to `atomic.SwapInt32()`. And to be able to do that, simply convert the `*State` pointer to `*int32`. This is possible because `State` has `int32` as its underlying type:

```
func SetAndGet(s *State, n State) State {
    return State(atomic.SwapInt32((*int32)(s), int32(n)))
}
```

Testing it:

```
var s State

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SetAndGet(&s, 1))
    fmt.Println(SetAndGet(&s, 2))
    fmt.Println(SetAndGet(&s, 3))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UYob-2Gzehn)):

```
0
1
2
```

Using the above solution, you get the same concurrency guarantees as you would if you would be using `int32` instead of `State`.

Comment: Does it means, in high concurrency situation, the atomic operations have the same concurrency effect on defined type 'State' as on 'int32'?

Comment: @JunfeiHu Yes, you get the same concurrency guarantees as if you would be using `int32`.